# AngularJS ignores form submit

Tags: forms, angularjs

I'm using AngularJS v1.2.13 to create a page with a form which will download a user's file on click.

I'm using [$sce](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce) to enable the injection of the file URL which works fine. 
However, the loading of the resource disables the form submit. I'm sure it has to do with the resource load because when I remove the load and hardcode the url it works fine. I've also created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/2387/) without it and have not been able to reproduce the problem there.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how it can be fixed?

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="viewProfileController"  data-ng-init="findOne();">
    <form method="get" action="{{downloadFileURL}}">
        <button type="submit" class="no-button comment-small" >
            Download File
        </button>
    </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('bop.viewProfile').controller('viewProfileController', [
    '$scope', 'Users', '$sce', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, Users, $sce, $routeParams) {

        $scope.downloadFileURL = '';

        // Find current user
        $scope.findOne = function() {
            Users.get({
                userId: $routeParams.userId
            }, function(user) {
                $scope.user = user;
                $scope.downloadFileURL = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl($scope.user.file.url);
            });
        };
}]);
```

Users Service:

```
var userServices = angular.module('bop.users', ['ngResource']);

userServices.factory('Users', ['$resource', function($resource) {

    return $resource(
        'users/:userId',
        { userId: '@_id' },
        { update: { method: 'PUT' } }
    );

}]);
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [`ng-submit`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit) attr instead of `action`? Alternatively try using `ng-disabled="true"` to explicitly enable it.

Comment: do you even need to submit button... You can use ng-click which is more angularjs way to do it...

Comment: I tried using ng-submit, that didn't work. If I used ng-click then I'd have to add a get request in the controller and it acts differently than what I need in some cases (such as post).

Comment: what do you mean by *'disables the form submit'*? is there an error in the console? is the button somehow disabled?

Comment: No error in the console, it just does nothing. It's as if I've put a button there and had not attached any action to it.